# Show shadowed mappings in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to determine if certain mappings are shadowing other mappings. Does anybody know if and how this is possible?

Edit: I have a large .vimrc. I want to know if old mappings I created when I was a (vim)beginner are shadowing native vim mappings.

Thanks

Comment: may I ask why you want to do that? you could use `nore` when you created the mapping, so that you mapping won't trigger other mappings. what is your final goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit: I have a large .vimrc. I want to know if old mappings I created
>   when I was a (vim)beginner are shadowing native vim mappings.

the short answer, you cannot know.

One thing needs to be clarified, the "**native vim mappings**". what does it mean? I guess you mean some built-in vim commands, like `dd`, `gg`, `G`... they are not mappings.

take the `dd` example, if you don't know `dd` exists, you create a mapping with `dd` to do something else, it's fine. and you cannot know if it will overwrite the built-in `dd (delete the current line)`.

Answer (score 2):

You may find `:map` useful here.

Comment: `:map` will only list the customized mappings right? not  "native" ones.

Comment: Yeah, he wanted to know the mappings "he" created, not the native ones. The native ones may be viewed with `:h index`.

Comment: OP added an `EDIT` in his question. :D